# How to can iterate over a JSON (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

I'm trying to load the comments whit AJAX, that I have in JSON format, but the problem is that only charges a comment.

Initially responsible for all the comments with html, but when entering a new comment I must add the new review and update the rest.

**JSON**

```
{'error':'false',
    fields:[{'pk':1,'title':'Test Title', 'body':'Test Body'}],
    {'votes':20,'cant':{1:20,2:30,3:4}}
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="list">
    <!-- sample javascript -->
    <li class="sample">
        <div class="image"><img src="" width="50" height="50"></div>
        <div class="rated">
            <div class="stars"><span></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="user"><a href=""></a></div>
        <div class="date"></div>
        <div class="body"></div>
    </li>


    <!-- Suppose we have 10 comments loaded, for initial use html --> 
    <li>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="avatar/2092974" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <div class="rated">
            <div class="stars"><span style="width:40%"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="user"><a href="">UserName</a></div>
        <div class="date">(2 minutes)</div>
        <div class="body">comment, test</div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**jQuery CODE UPDATED**

```
$("ul.list li").not('.sample').remove();
$.each(d.fields[0], function(i,item){
  var v = $("ul.list li.sample").clone(true).removeClass('sample');
  $(".image img", v).attr('src','http://www.cuevana.tv/avatar/2092974');
  $(".rated", v).find('.stars span').css('width',item['score'] + '%');
  $(".user a", v).text(item['user']);
  $(".date", v).text('('+item['date']+')');
  $(".body", v).text(item['body']);
  $("ul.list").append(v)
});
```

**My Question**: How can I update all the comments and enter the new, I need to iterate the data but I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("ul.list").html(v);
```

replace with

```
$("ul.list").append(v);   //Or Prepend
```

.html will replace the entire content with new one :)

Comment: You can help me please.

Comment: @user3258963 Sure. var v = $("ul.list li.sample").clone(true).removeClass('sample'); is fine. Why dont you remove tat each and simply append the entire structure to UL

Comment: You propose, because no term to understand.

Comment: @user3258963 I can't code the entire thing here but i can give an example : $("ul.list").append("<li><div class="image">img src=" + data.fields[0].pk +" width="50" height="50"></div></li>");  /*Now i am not sure about the .pk thing*/ but you can try this

Comment: This not work,that returns multiple objects in fields.

Comment: @user3258963 on objects use EACH ..store them in variables and then use my above code replacing <img src=" + data.fields[0].pk +" /> with <img src=" + image_variable +" />